# Swift infinite background scrolling

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, scroll, background

I am trying to develop a simple game, with that game i need a infinite scrolling background. It is working for 2 times, and after the image has scrolled for 2 times it is adding the image to late and not with the right position.

Here is my code right now.

**Move Background function**

```
func moveBackground() {
    let backgroundVelocity : CGFloat = 10.0
    self.enumerateChildNodesWithName("background", usingBlock: { (node, stop) -> Void in
        if let bg = node as? SKSpriteNode {
            bg.position = CGPoint(x: bg.position.x, y: bg.position.y  - backgroundVelocity)

            // Checks if bg node is completely scrolled off the screen, if yes, then puts it at the end of the other node.
            if bg.position.y <= -bg.size.height {
                bg.position = CGPointMake(bg.position.x , bg.position.y + bg.size.width * 2)
            }
        }
    })
}
```

**Initialize Scrolling Background function**

```
func initializingScrollingBackground() {
    self.addChild(background)
    for var index = 0; index < 2; index++ {
        let bg = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "bg")
        bg.position = CGPoint(x: 0 , y: index * Int(bg.size.height))
        bg.anchorPoint = CGPointZero
        bg.name = "background"
        bg.zPosition = 10
        self.addChild(bg)

    }
}
```

Hope you guys can help me out with this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this line:

```
bg.position = CGPointMake(bg.position.x , bg.position.y + bg.size.width * 2)
                                                          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

shouldn't you use `height` and not `width`?

Comment: Cheers mate, that did the trick. Don't know how i didn't noticed that!